# Does mongodb upsert use the query field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

When using update with upsert does the driver combine the query and $set objects.

Here is some example code

```
db.collection('objects').update({_key: 'test1'}, {$set: {a:1}}, {upsert: true, w: 1}, callback);
```

When I do this, if the document test1 doesn't exist mongo seems to insert the following document.

```
{
 _id: ,
 _key: 'test1',
  a: 1
}
```

So it takes the key from the query and uses it as a field along with `a:1`

Is this any different than :

```
var data = {
   _key : 'test1',
   a: 1
};

db.collection('objects').update({_key: 'test1'}, {$set: data}, {upsert: true, w: 1}, callback);
```

Is the second one going to be slower due to overwriting the _key. There is an index on _key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically no, the values specified in the query do not overwrite where the document matching that query exists.

How an ["upsert"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-behavior) basically works is that the conditions set in the query portion first look for a document matching those conditions. Where the document exists, then any arguments supplied in the "update document" portion of the statement are used to write to the document(s) that match. In this case, there are just fields specified with the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator, so these are the only fields that are touched as opposed to sending a whole object which would overwrite the existing document.

Should the document have not matched, then first, whatever values are specified in the query condition are written to the new document. This makes sense since you were asking for a document that met those conditions but was not there.

Then (but really all at once) any values in the "update document" portion of the statement are also applied to the new document. You can also specify fields you want to create on "insert" which are not present in the query portion using the [**`$setOnInsert`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) operator, so those values are only used on creation.

In fact a good way to demonstrate this is to do two "upsert" operations as follows:

```
db.test.update({ "a": "test" },{ "$set": { "b": "data" } },{ "upsert": true});
db.test.update({ "a": "test" },{ "b": "data" },{ "upsert": true});
```

Without any of the update operators here you are just sending a whole document the second iteration. This means when the "insert" occurs on the first you have a document like this:

```
{ "a": "test", "b": "data" }
```

But of course when you perform the second update which matches the document with field "a" equal to "test" then the resulting document is this:

```
{ "b": "data" }
```

Which is a clear demonstration that the query portion of the statement is not used to write on an actual update. So this only happens on insertion and only when used with an update operator present in the update document portion of the statement

Comment: What if we update with a different _key value than the original, var data = {
   _key : 'test2',
   a: 1
};

Comment: @chianh Then you specify the value you want to "change" in the update portion: `{ "_key": "test1},{ "$set": { "_key": "test2", "a": 1 } }`. Query documents are for "matching" and are only applied on insertion. Whatever you put in the update document is applied. You cannot "overwrite" `_id` BTW.

Comment: Thanks @Neil. I am not clear enough: in the case the _key=test1 doesn't exist, will this upsert _key=test2?

Comment: @chianh An upsert means that if no document is found that matches then a new document is inserted. Since a value is specified in the update document for _key as "test2" if no document is found with "test1" a new one with "test2" would be created, overwise just overwriting the value of _key because you asked it to. Which is the reverse case of the question asked.